# Namespace and scopes

Tags: python, scope

i've been recently trying to learn all by myself python, and came up with this cool explanation in the docs about python language:
[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

my problem is with this snippet:

```
    def scope_test():
     def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"

    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"

    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam = "global spam"

    spam = "test spam"
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)

  scope_test()
  print("In global scope:", spam)
```

when printing this out, i'm getting:

```
After local assignment: test spam
After nonlocal assignment: nonlocal spam
After global assignment: nonlocal spam
In global scope: global spam
```

which seems not so clear why.
the last and one line before doesn't make sense to me.
**can anyone explain please?**
(my way of thinking says that the third print should be "global", and then it make sense to be at the forth line "global". but the answer speaks otherwise)

Comment: I think in your do_nonlocal function you are *creating* a nonlocal variable called `spam`. So when you go to print `spam` you find that nonlocal variable first, before the global variable `spam` is found.

Answer (score 0):

You are only importing the global value of the variable "spam" in the "do_global()" function, thus in the "scope_test()" context (where you print the first line), you still have the nonlocal value "nonlocal spam". If you add the "global spam" line before printing the third line, you'll get the desired result.

Last, since the fourth print is outside the "scope_test()" context, it automatically takes the global value of the variable, which you set before, and it's "global spam"

Comment: do you mean "before the nonlocal function?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up your indentation a bit.

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"

    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"

    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam = "global spam"

    spam = "test spam"
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)

scope_test()
print("In global scope:", spam)
```

Each of the three inner functions differ in *which* variable `spam` they create or modify.

- `do_local` creates a new variable, never to be seen again after `do_local` returns.
- `do_nonlocal` creates or modifies a variable in the scope of `scope_test`, since that's the closest enclosing scope.
- `do_global` creates or modifies a variable in the global scope, *outside* of `scope_test`.

Each of the three calls to `print` in `scope_test`, though, use the *same* variable, the one defined directly in `scope_test` with `spam = "test spam"`. That means that neither the call to `do_local` nor the call to `do_gobal` affect what they output; only `do_nonlocal` changes the particular `spam` pass as an argument to `print`.

Note that the call to `print` in the global scope would fail with a name error if used before you actually called `scope_test`, because that's the only thing (via the call to `do_global`) that defines `spam` in the global scope in this script.